# Get Video File and save using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, video, file-io

I am working on MVC4 web api,where I need to get video file from server path("C:\web_app\content\video\demo.mp4") and need to save that video to the different location("C:\video\demo.mp4").Video format is "MP4".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, what is your problem and what have you tried?

Comment: how to get video as object and save it?how to create video object or file stream that i can use to save it somewhere else

Comment: Surely typing into google is much easier than writing a SO question?

Comment: i did search on google.but no use.thats why i asked question

Comment: So you are basically looking for a controller action to upload the file ?

Comment: video file is there on server. i need to read that file and save it diffterent location with different name.for this i need  to get that file as stream or somthing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using system.IO;

    class program
    { 
      static void main()
       {
         // Local Files 
         File.Copy("path", "new Path");
       }
    }
```